# JasperServer Connection Pool Error on JDBC SQL Server with SSL

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I’m attempting to use the JDBC SQL Server Driver with JasperServer for reports.  I’m using the latest driver jar available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774.  The filename is sqljdbc42.jar.

I’m attempting to configure SSL over the connection.  My connection string looks like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://my.hostname.com:1433;databaseName=Reporting;EncryptionMethod=SSL;encrypt=true
```

When I set this up in Jasper Studio, it works perfectly.  I’m able to connect and can see through Wireshark that the connection is secure.  However, when I use the exact same connection through Jasper Server, I get the following errors:

Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. Show Details

The full stack dump is below.

I’m really at a loss, but it’s imperative this connection be made with SSL enabled.  When I used only EncryptionMethod=SSL, it connected but wasn’t encrypted.  As mentioned, the exact same connection string works properly through Studio, just not my local version of Jasper Server.

Any help on this would very greatly be appreciated!

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.testConnection(JdbcDataSourceService.java:85) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.connection.JdbcConnectionStrategy.createConnection(JdbcConnectionStrategy.java:76) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.connection.JdbcConnectionStrategy.createConnection(JdbcConnectionStrategy.java:45) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.connection.ConnectionsManager.createConnection(ConnectionsManager.java:72) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.connection.ConnectionsJaxrsService.createConnection(ConnectionsJaxrsService.java:84) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor502.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.doFilter(StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.java:161) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:143) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:217) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:217) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:57) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:83) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:80) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:63) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:618) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not create a validated object, cause: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1191) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106) ... 111 more
Close
```

Comment: What OS is Jasper Server running on, as opposed to Jasper Studio? Same or different? Can you run Wireshark on the server to see if any attempt is made to establish the connection securely? You may have a mismatch between the cipher suites enabled on either end of the connection.